# Redirect unregistered users to the site on local machine

Tags: networking, routing, redirection, gateway, dhcp-server

- I have a server 192.168.0.3 (SERVER). Running Ubuntu Server + DHCP server + Apache;
- The router 192.168.0.1 (ROUTER) (I haven't access to it);
- I have a web-application on SERVER for registration users in the network by applying specific configuration (in DHCP server) for them;
- Users are in the subnet 192.168.0.0/16;

I can config DHCP server to give unregistered machines my SERVER as default gateway.
So how can i **redirect** all incoming http requests from unregistered machines to my **local web-app** 192.168.0.3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -dport 80 -j DNAT –to-destination 1.2.3.4:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to setup a specal DNS server that responds all DNS queries with your server's IP and setup Apache's virtual server to accept request for any host (i.e. *:80 + *:443).

The trick is, after login, the DNS server must start providing correct DNS results as opposed fake ones. You cannot simply change the settings again in DHCP because the default lease time will be too long and/or users have to disconnect to pickup the new settings.

Many Wi-Fi log-in system uses this architecture, so you may be able to find an open source solution.

Comment: yes, this method is bad because of the thing, that users will have fake addresses cashed and won't be able to browse sites for some time after registration

Answer (score 0):

### I have found one another way.

1. Give unregistered machines SERVER as default gateway.
2. redirect *port 80* to the web-server using *iptables*

But i don't know exactly how to do it :)